# Are drop bears dangerous?

Tags: folklore

I recently visited Australia, Sydney region. I've been warned about animals called drop bears. What kind of animal is it? Is it dangerous ?

Comment: No outdoor site is complete without the drop bear reference.

Comment: I can't decide whether to upvote this question or give it a close vote. It's got to be one or the other...!

Comment: some more information about Drop Bears and how to avoid attacks: http://australianmuseum.net.au/Drop-Bear

Comment: @HorusKol you do realize drop bears aren't real, right?

Comment: Don't be afraid of Drop Bears. They're attracted to your raisin peelers. If you throw your raisin peelers down and run, you can save your self from harm.

Comment: I had never heard of Drop Bears before, but they sound vaguely related to the Jackalope of the southwestern US.

Comment: I think this question is quite valid. As false as it is, I've convinced a good handful of people about the existence of drop bears, so having a question dispel the myth seems useful to me. If they existed, it'd be a major issue for any outdoor activities near trees.

Comment: Like an Austrailian Jackalope?

Answer (score 12):

No, they aren't real animals.

[Here's a wiki link for it.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_bear)

Its one of those things people like to tell tourists to watch out for so they'll look stupid.

Comment: I didn't feel stupid with a garlic-smelling colander on my head.

Comment: on the other hand - almost everything that moves in Australia is dangerous: spiders, snakes, magpies (especially if you're cycling for some reason), emus, salties, etc...