# What fictitious wilderness animals are there as tourist attractions?

Tags: folklore

Having read this [question on drop bears](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/168/are-drop-bears-dangerous). I have been wondering what other fictitious animals are there in other parts of the world that have been invented to amuse/confuse tourists.

Has anyone compiled a list?

Do these animals share any common features?

In particular I'm interested in the more "modern" fictitious animals such as drop bears or haggis rather than more traditional mythical beasts like dragons or the minotaur.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Fictitious animals which hardly have a thing to do with most of the outdoor activities.

Comment: I think it is good to know about fictious animals so you can´t be fooled by locals who tell you "to be cautious not to wake the jackalope" or stuff like this.

Comment: You just *might* frame it like "What are good tourist places in the part of the world where major tourist attraction is Fictitious wild species?" that just might find a place in Travel.SE. I doubt though!

Comment: @Paul: Hmm, yet, I am not personally convinced, no offence mate. May be mods will handle it in much better ways! :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Outdoors, as per our scope. WedaPashi's comment is a possible option, but even that is likely to be more suited to our sister site, Travel.

Comment: @Paul: Anyway mate, if anyone ask me (trying to fool me saying)not to camp, trail-walk in Australia as some Drop Bear might harm me, am I gonna be bothered? No, I am not!

Comment: Thats what I was talking about: *mods can handle that in much better ways* :-) Cheers!

Comment: Geesh guys, lighten up a little.  I wouldn't say every myth or fictitious thing is OK here, but this one seems pretty harmless, and rather fun too.

Comment: My personal favorite is the Jackalope that inhabits the dry areas of the western US.  You run across them from Arizona to Montana.